# How Javascript works in memory?

Tags: javascript

Hey everyone i got a question about how Javascript works in memory

i've heard that every execution context has a space in memory for that execution context

so if that so that's mean that all the variables on the program doesn't sits randomly in memory but rather sits in a memory block of the execution context where they created

now i will try to explain it visually

let's say we have a program and inside that program we have a function called `createVars`

```
function createVars(){
   var name = 'John',lastName = 'Doe',age = 24;
}
```

when we invoke the `createVars` function it will create a new execution context and that execution context will have it's own block in memory where it now reserved for that execution context variables and the this keyword and the outer reference

so here is an example let's say we have an unoccupied place in memory

[image]

and now we invoke `createVars()`

[image]

does it look like that in memory or the variables are randomly placed ?

Comment: You can apply reverse engineering for understand what happens.

Comment: You don't, can't, and won't know. There's nothing in the spec that defines how things are laid out in memory, so it's implementation-dependent. You'd have a potentially different answer for every JS runtime.

Comment: That depends on the actual implementation of a JS engine.

Comment: @JaredSmith You can absolutely. The source code of some of the JS engines is freely available. And even if not there are debuggers that can help with that.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, I think you and are talking about different levels of abstraction here. Yes, certainly you can go read the V8 or SpiderMonkey or whatever code and see how it's done *today*, right now, in those specific implementations, but there's no guarantee that it will stay that way or be the same in other implementations and there's no way (that I know of, I'd be fascinated to be proved wrong!) for the Javascript code *itself* to know how the underlying host is allocating memory.

Comment: @JaredSmith _"...for the Javascript code itself to know how the underlying host is allocating memory"_ - Which is not the topic of the question, or I did miss that part :/ Your comment just seems a bit too general to me. It _would_ be possible. If it is feasible, or if OP is able to do this, is a different topic.

Comment: "*let's say we have an unoccupied place in memory*" - uh, what do you know about memory layout in general? Do you know how it works in other languages? Are you familiar with the terms heap and stack? "*does it look like that in memory*" - not really. "*the variables are randomly placed*" - no absolutely not, it needs to be deterministic for the engine to work.

Comment: I remembered about this article I read a while back, it might help: https://felixgerschau.com/javascript-memory-management